# Android: How to extends my Activity class with RoboActivity + ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, roboguice

I would like to use RoboActivity with my activity, but I don't know how to do that coz my current activity extends already ActionBarActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Extend RoboActivity from ActionBarActivity then MainActivity extends from RoboActivity.

Comment: RoboActivity class and ActionBarActivity class are librairies class, not mine!

Comment: Then it is not possible in Java. You cannot extend class from multiple classes.

Answer (score 6):

For RoboGuice 3 simply extend from RoboActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply copy the relevant RoboActivity parts into your subclass of ActionBarActivity.  From the official docs https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Using-your-own-BaseActivity-with-RoboGuice:

> In case your base activity class already extends a different library, the best way to get all the power of RoboGuice is to copy all the code contained in RoboActivity.

An example is also provided therein.